# check entry inputs in tkinter using a function

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I trying to create physics calculator using python tkinter but I find it quite difficult. I have done this calculator in Command line interface but I a bit different with tkinter. basically, I have 5 entry boxes and above each one of them a button. the user will insert values in three of them and should press the button on top of each unknown value to make the calculation and get the result. my main issue is how can I create a function that evaluates the inputs in my entry boxes and make the calculation then print the results inside the entry box. I made some coding but unfortunately the operation is not working due to few mistakes.

here is my coding part:

```
from Tkinter import *
import math

class calculator():

    def is_positive_number(number): # validation function
         if number <= 0:
             return False
         else :
             return True

    def value_of_time(prompt):
        while True: # loop command for time 
            try:     
                valid = False
                while not valid:
                    value = float((prompt))
                    if is_positive_number(value):
                        valid = True
                        return value
                    else :
                        valid = False
                        print ('I donot know what is happening')
            except ValueError:
                print("Oops, unfortunately this is a wrong input, please try again.")
                #better try again... Return to the start of the loop
                continue
            else:
                #value was successfully parsed!
                #we're ready to exit the loop.
                break


    def input_of_box(prompt):
        while True: # loop for initial velocity
            try:
                value = float(input(prompt))
                return value
            except ValueError:
                print("Oops, we are you not typing a number, please try again.")
                #better try again... Return to the start of the loop
                continue
            else:
                #value was successfully parsed!
                #we're ready to exit the loop.
                break


    # def minput(numberofinput):
        if numberofinput == 1:
            t = value_of_time("Enter the time that takes an object to accelerate in seconds:")
            return 
        elif numberofinput == 2:
            u = input_of_box("Enter the initial velocity in m/s:")
            return
        elif numberofinput == 2:
            v = input_of_box("Enter the final velocity in m/s:")
            return



    def my_calculation(mvariables): # this function is to operate the calculation

        if mvariables == 1:
            a = (v-u) /(t)
            mentery1 = a
            return 

        elif mvariables == 2:
            v = u + a*t
            mentery2 = v
            return
        elif mvariables == 3:
            u = a*t - v
            mentery3 = t

        elif mvariables == 4:
            t = (v - u)/a
            mentery3 = t
            return
        elif mvariables == 5:
            s = (v**2-u**2)/2*a
            mentery4 = s
        else:
            print ('there is an error')




    cal = Tk()
    cal.configure(background='sky blue')
    a = StringVar()
    u = StringVar()
    v = StringVar()
    t = StringVar()
    s = StringVar()


    cal.geometry('650x420+350+225')

    cal.title('Main Menu')

    # here we start greating buttons and entry boxes
    m_label = Label(text='Calculator',fg = 'Navy', font=("Helvetica", 20,"bold italic"), bg='sky blue')
    m_label.pack()

    button1 = Button(cal,text='A',fg='white',bg='dark green',bd =3, width=4, command= lambda : my_calculation(1))
    button1.place(x=92,y=210)

    mentery1 = Entry(cal, textvariable = a ,width=10,bd =3)
    mentery1.place(x=82,y=240)

    button2 = Button(cal,text='U',fg='white',bg='dark green',bd =3, width=4, command= lambda : my_calculation(3))
    button2.place(x=192,y=210)

    mentery2 = Entry(cal, textvariable = u ,width=10,bd =3)
    mentery2.place(x=182,y=240)

    button3 = Button(cal,text='V',fg='white',bg='dark green',bd =3, width=4, command= lambda : my_calculation(2))
    button3.place(x=292,y=210)

    mentery3 = Entry(cal, textvariable = v ,width=10,bd =3)
    mentery3.place(x=282,y=240)

    button4 = Button(cal,text='T',fg='white',bg='dark green',bd =3, width=4,command= lambda : my_calculation(4))
    button4.place(x=392,y=210)

    mentery4 = Entry(cal, textvariable = t ,width=10,bd =3)
    mentery4.place(x=382,y=240)

    button5 = Button(cal,text='S',fg='white',bg='dark green',bd =3, width=4,command= lambda : my_calculation(5))
    button5.place(x=492,y=210)

    mentery5 = Entry(cal, textvariable = s , width=10,bd =3)
    mentery5.place(x=482,y=240)
    # end of button commands

app = calculator()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For validating the input, do the following:

```
def returnValidatedInput(entry):
    value = entry.get() # Get the text in the 'entry' widget
    evaluation = eval(value) # Evaluate 'value'
    return evaluation
```

And for inserting the answers into the entries (it's not called *printing the answers into the entries*):

```
def insertAnswer(entry, answer):
    entry.delete(0, 'end') # Be sure the entry is empty, if it is not, clear it
    entry.insert(END, str(answer)) # Insert the answer into the 'entry' widget.
```